# If a subspace of $L^p\cap L^q$ is closed with respect to both norms, the norms are equivalent on this subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure, $1< p,q<\infty$ and  let $X$ be a linear subspace of $L^p(\mu)\cap L^q(\mu).$ Suppose $X$ is closed in $L^p(\mu)$ and also $X$ is closed in $L^q(\mu)$. Prove that $\|.\|_p$ and $\|.\|_q$ are equivalent on $X$.

---

Truly speaking I have no idea how to start. I know I have to find the some constant that that will show the equivalent on the norms.

Comment: Show that the identity operator from $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)$ to  $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert_q)$ is an isomorphism. Towards this end, the Closed Graph Theorem would prove useful.

Comment: Okay, as your advice i took identity map which is bijection.To prove map is bounded I used closed graph theorem where i got $x_n$ goes to x in $L^p$ norm and $x_n$ goes to y in $L^q$ norm. Then i showed x=y a.e but i need x=y. How can i show x=y?

Comment: ae is all you need. Elements in $L_p$ are equivalence classes. Functions are in the same equivalence class if they are equal ae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding the comment by David Mitra: the identity map $I:(X,\|\cdot\|_p)\to (X,\|\cdot\|_q)$ has the graph
$$\{(x,x) : x\in X\}\subset L_p\times L_q$$
which is a closed set by the assumption. Since both $(X,\|\cdot\|_p)$ and $ (X,\|\cdot\|_q) $ are Banach spaces, the Closed Graph Theorem  shows that $I$ is a bounded operator.

The same applies with $p$ and $q$ interchanged; thus $I$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Does this argument work if $p$ or $q$ or both were infinity?