# Prove that the $L^p$ and $L^q$ norms are equivalent on a closed subspace $X$ of $L^p(\mu) \cap L^q(\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I was looking for a few clarifications on a post here on stack exchange, namely this one

[If a subspace of $L^p\cap L^q$ is closed with respect to both norms, the norms are equivalent on this subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1475139/966646)

My questions stem from this answer given:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478213/966646

Here are my questions:

1. Does $\mu$ need to be of positive measure, or could $\mu$ just be an arbitrary measure?
2. How does knowing that $I$ is bounded help prove the isomorphism?
3. Once we get that $I$ is an Isomorphism, how can we conclude that the norms in question are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $\mu$ is not a positive measure, then $\int \vert u\vert^p\mathrm{d}\mu$ can be negative and $\Vert u\Vert_p=\left(\int \vert u\vert^p\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/p}$ is not well-defined.
2. $I$ is the identity map, as such it is automatically bijective and linear. It only remains to show that it is continuous or, equivalently, bounded.
3. If $I$ is bounded, this means that there is a constant $C>0$ such that $\Vert u\Vert_q=\Vert Iu\Vert_q\leq C\Vert u\Vert_p$. Since $p$ and $q$ are interchangeable, this implies the equivalency of the norms.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I do have one last question can either $p$ or $q$ or both be infinity?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why this wouldn't work for $p$ or $q$ being infinity. However, I'm a bit unsure now, because the OP in the linked question asked this explicitly for $p,q<\infty$. If you want to be 100% sure, I suggest you ask this in a comment over at the answer you're referring to.

Comment: Last question, when you say $\Vert u\Vert_p=\left(\int \vert u\vert^p\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/p}$ is not well-defined, what do you mean?

Comment: @EmmaK Suppose e.g. $p=2$ and $\int\vert u\vert^p\mathrm{d}\mu=-1$. Then, $\Vert u\Vert_p=\sqrt{-1}$ which is not well-defined.